# upload CSV file via curl to Ruby on Rails backend

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv, curl

I am trying to send a file to a controller action via `curl`.
Here is what I tried:

```
curl -F "file=wb.csv" http://localhost:3000/api/v1/process_data?api_key=Dp9Kv7j1y-FYytd-tYsAsSNic3ox
```

However, in my controller, I checked the content of the params sent and it just returns the filename `wb.csv` instead of a csv attachment:

```
{"file"=>"wb.csv", "api_key"=>"Dp9Kv7j1y-FYytd-tYsAsSNic3ox", "format"=>"json", "action"=>"import_csv", "controller"=>"api/v1/growth_utils"}
```

I'd like to achieve the same thing as if I was posting from a form on the UI:

```
<%= form_tag import_csv_admin_growths_path, multipart: true do %>
  <%= file_field_tag :file %>
  <%= submit_tag "Import" %>
<%end%>
```

Which in the controller action has params:

```
{"file"=>
      #<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007faa0543b7d0
       @content_type="text/csv",
       @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"wb.csv\"\r\nContent-Type: text/csv\r\n",
       @original_filename="wb.csv",
       @tempfile=#<File:/var/folders/zq/kk1mrjjn52zdf8120c4z4tb80000gn/T/RackMultipart20180405-21787-17k4lup>>,
     "commit"=>"Import",
     "format"=>"csv",
     "action"=>"import_csv",
     "controller"=>"admin/growths"}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your curl you are doing it wrong. You are sending the file name as parameter not the file itself

```
curl -F import_file=@wb.csv http://localhost:3000/api/v1/process_data?api_key=Dp9Kv7j1y-FYytd-tYsAsSNic3ox.
```

try this. this is same as your second output and that's how rails handle file uploads.

Comment: That worked. thanks. The issue was quotes around `file=@wb.csv` ?\